# Failed to add table in Excel using Microsoft Graph

Tags: excel, rest, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add a table in Excel using Microsoft Graph following [this doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/tablecollection_add).

I already created an Excel file and got my DriveItemId. I tried it on [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer):

**POST**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/01*****/workbook/tables/add
```

**Request body**

```
{
  "address": "Table1",
  "hasHeaders": true
}
```

But it returned this for me:

```
Status Code: 400
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidArgument",
        "message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d3bc1426-db8d-43aa-873b-aaf1326c387a",
            "date": "2017-04-28T22:16:03"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample shown in the documentation link could be confusing. It is meant to be a placeholder for actual values.

Here is a sample API call to create a table on a worksheet named Sheet1. It invokes `add` action on the tables collection with the parameters in body. Provide the full range address in the "address" property.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01XTAKFWENRFW3SKBKKNGYEJDCOHUG7RLP/workbook/tables/add

{
  "address": "Sheet1!A1:D5",
  "hasHeaders": true
}

Alternatively, you could also invoke this on the worksheet's table collection. If you do so, you can skip the sheet name in the address. Example:

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01XTAKFWENRFW3SKBKKNGYEJDCOHUG7RLP/workbook/worksheets/sheet1/tables/add

{
    "address": "H1:L5"  }

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it works! Added a PR [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/1166) for this demo.